# If $F$ is equicontinuous and $\phi$ is Lipshitz continuous, then $G = \{\phi\circ f:f\in F\}$ is equicontinous.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $(X,d_x), (Y,d_y), (Z,d_z)$ are metric spaces. Let $F$ be a family of functions from $X$ to $Y$, and $F$ is equicontinuous at $x_0\in X$.

If $\phi:Y\rightarrow Z$ is Lipshitz, then show that $G = \{\phi(f(x))|f\in F, x\in X\}$ is also equicontinuous at $x_0\in X$.

My attempt:

$(1)$ Since $F$ is equicontinous at $x_0$: given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ s.t. $\forall y\in X$, $d_x(x_0,y)<\delta \Rightarrow d_y(f(x_0),f(y))<\epsilon$ for all $f\in F$.

Also since $\phi$ is Lipshitz, $\exists C>0$ such that $d_z(\phi(x),\phi(y))\leq Cd_y(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in Y$.

Now to show $G$ is equicontinuous:

Given $\epsilon>0$ choose $\delta$ from $(1)$ so that for all $y\in X$ we have $d_x(x_0,y)<\delta \Rightarrow d_z(\phi(f(x_0)),\phi(f(y))\leq Cd_y(f(x_0),(f(y))<C\epsilon$.

I think this completes the proof, since $C$ is fixed. 
Is this a correct approach?

Also, would I be correct in saying this approach can work identically if $\phi$ is Holderian instead of Lipshitz?